# Varying speeds on LAN port

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, lan

So, I just got a new optical fibre internet connection for my home. My ISP provides me with a ZTE F660 GPon Modem.

When I check for internet speeds, on `LAN Port 1`, I get around `190Mbps`, while on `LAN Port 2` through `4`, I consistently get only around `91Mbps`. I noticed this variance because my second router was connected on `LAN4`, and the WiFi speeds on it were around `91Mbps`.

I have tested these speeds averaging out repetitive outcomes, using the same cord, same laptop and nearly identical network conditions (zero external loads).

Can someone explain to me why the speeds are varying on different LAN ports of the same modem?

Edit: After a little bit of exploring the modem settings, I came across "user interface" status. [LAN 2, 100M, Full  Duplex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1E5v.png).

But, an empty port is shown so:

[LAN 3, Linkdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiYvv.png)

In a disconnected port, the speed is not being shown, which may mean that the modem doesn't limit port speed.

But, when I connect the same wire from Port 1 to Port 2, it changes from `1000M` to `100M`.

I have no idea what is going on, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you kept a log of this? Can you keep a log of this?  Then approach your ISP. This is step 1 before we look at other things.

Comment: Any QoS setup that may give priority to port 1 over the others?

Comment: Have you checked the link speed (not throughput) yet? It may be limited to 100 Mbit/s. It could be a power-saving feature.

Comment: @John It may be tedious, but I think I can make a man-made log.

Comment: @LPChip I don't see any option called QoS on my modem.

Comment: @DanielB I searched for such an option on my modem, but I couldn't find anything on a rough look. There's a lot of settings over there that I get overwhelmed. If you can tell me some common terms, I can look for it.

Comment: I have the same router and had a similar issue. My network interface was only showing 100M - until I plugged in a gigabit capable device. My network interface changed from 100M and now shows 1000M. Seems like the port serves traffic speeds based on the device you have plugged in.

Comment: @DavidP Yeah, I did try connecting a gigabit-capable device on both port 1 and 2. 1 showed 1000M and 2 showed 100M. My ISP gave me some bs answer on how gigabit is unmanageable among 4 ports and hence only one port gives out GE. I solved my requirement by connecting a Gigabit Router and a Gigabit Unmanaged Switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, only the first port was gigabit; my ISP was trying to save money on their free modems by installing a gigabit modem with only one gigabit port.

How dare they!